# C#/XNA interface usage, repeating functions

Tags: c#, xna

Essentially I'm wondering if this implementation of an interface is correct.  I mostly don't like having to repeat the exact same getters and setters.  Is there a better way or is this alright?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;

namespace TetrisPro
{
    interface Block
    {
        Color GetColor();
        Position[] GetPosition();
        Position GetPosition(int i);
        Position[] GetOldPosition();
        Position GetOldPosition(int i);
    }
    class Square : Block
    {
        private Color color;
        private Position[] position;
        private Position[] oldPosition;

        public Square()
        {
            this.color = Color.Firebrick;
            this.position = new Position[4];
            this.oldPosition = new Position[4];
            SetPosition();
        }
        public Square(int x, int y)
        {
            this.color = Color.GreenYellow;
            this.position = new Position[4];
            this.oldPosition = new Position[4];
            SetPosition();
            SetPosition(x, y);
        }

        public void SetPosition()
        {
            this.position[0] = new Position(0, 0);
            this.position[1] = new Position(0, 1);
            this.position[2] = new Position(1, 0);
            this.position[3] = new Position(1, 1);
        }
        public void SetPosition(int x, int y)
        {
            this.oldPosition = position;
            this.position[0] = new Position(x, y);
            this.position[1] = new Position(x, y + 1);
            this.position[2] = new Position(x + 1, y);
            this.position[3] = new Position(x + 1, y + 1);
        }
        public Color GetColor()
        {
            return this.color;
        }
        public Position[] GetPosition()
        {
            return this.position;
        }
        public Position GetPosition(int i)
        {
            return this.position[i];
        }
        public Position[] GetOldPosition()
        {
            return this.oldPosition;
        }
        public Position GetOldPosition(int i)
        {
            return this.oldPosition[i];
        }
    }
    class Line : Block
    {
        private Color color;
        private Position[] position;
        private Position[] oldPosition;

        public Line()
        {
            this.color = Color.BlueViolet;
            this.position = new Position[4];
            this.oldPosition = new Position[4];
            SetPosition();
        }

        public void SetPosition()
        {
            this.position[0] = new Position(0, 0);
            this.position[1] = new Position(0, 1);
            this.position[2] = new Position(0, 2);
            this.position[3] = new Position(0, 3);
        }
        public void SetPosition(int x, int y)
        {
            this.oldPosition = position;
            this.position[0] = new Position(x, y);
            this.position[1] = new Position(x, y + 1);
            this.position[2] = new Position(x, y + 2);
            this.position[3] = new Position(x, y + 3);
        }
        public Color GetColor()
        {
            return this.color;
        }
        public Position[] GetPosition()
        {
            return this.position;
        }
        public Position GetPosition(int i)
        {
            return this.position[i];
        }
        public Position[] GetOldPosition()
        {
            return this.oldPosition;
        }
        public Position GetOldPosition(int i)
        {
            return this.oldPosition[i];
        }
    }
    class ZLeft : Block
    {
        private Color color;
        private Position[] position;
        private Position[] oldPosition;

        public ZLeft()
        {
            this.color = Color.DodgerBlue;
            this.position = new Position[4];
            this.oldPosition = new Position[4];
            SetPosition();
        }

        public void SetPosition()
        {
            this.position[0] = new Position(0, 0);
            this.position[1] = new Position(1, 0);
            this.position[2] = new Position(1, 1);
            this.position[3] = new Position(2, 1);
        }
        public void SetPosition(int x, int y)
        {
            this.oldPosition = position;
            this.position[0] = new Position(x, y);
            this.position[1] = new Position(x + 1, y);
            this.position[2] = new Position(x + 1, y + 1);
            this.position[3] = new Position(x + 2, y + 1);
        }
        public Color GetColor()
        {
            return this.color;
        }
        public Position[] GetPosition()
        {
            return this.position;
        }
        public Position GetPosition(int i)
        {
            return this.position[i];
        }
        public Position[] GetOldPosition()
        {
            return this.oldPosition;
        }
        public Position GetOldPosition(int i)
        {
            return this.oldPosition[i];
        }
    }
    // ... more classes
}
```

Comment: Check for the snippet creation walkthrough on MSDN.  It can help if you want to implement some properties and getter + setter over dozen of class without having to rewrite everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please read [.NET Naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229040%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), in particular interfaces should be prefixed with `I` (`Block` => `IBlock`).

- Your interface doesn't include SetPosition while all classes that implement this interface do have it.
- There is no need to declare both `GetPosition()` and `GetPosition(int)` as latter doesn't add any value to interface, can be implemented as an extension method if needed.
- When your objects are created via parameterless constructor you get an inconsistent state (OldPosition is not initialised with `Position` objects)
- You mentioned getters and setters while you don't have any properties defined. I would replace `GetPosition()` with read-only property, and define only one `SetPosition(int,int)` method as an object mutator. If you do need parameterless `SetPosition` you can create extension method for `IBlock` interface that will call `SetPosition(0, 0)`
- In order to avoid repeating implementation you can consider creating a base class, so that derived classes will only need to override `SetPosition(int,int)`.

  ```
  public interface IBlock
  {
      Color Color { get; }
      Position[] Position { get; }
      Position[] OldPosition { get; }
      void SetPosition(int x, int y);
  }

  public class Block : IBlock
  {
      private readonly Point[] _structure;

      public Color Color { get; private set; }
      public Position[] Position { get; private set; }
      public Position[] OldPosition { get; private set; }

      public Block(Color color, Point[] structure, int x = 0, int y = 0)
      {
          Color = color;
          _structure = structure;
          //to properly initialise both Old and current positions
          SetPosition(0, 0);
          SetPosition(x, y);
      }

      private Position[] BuildPosition(int x, int y)
      {
          return Array.ConvertAll(_structure, point => new Position(x + point.X, y + point.Y));
      }

      public void SetPosition(int x, int y)
      {
          OldPosition = Position;
          Position = BuildPosition(x, y);
      }
  }

  public class Line : Block
  {
      public Line(int x = 0, int y = 0)
          : base(Color.BlueViolet, new Point[] { new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 1), new Point(0, 2), new Point(0, 3) }, x, y)
      {

      }
  }
  ```

Comment: You shouldn't be calling virtual members from a base class (`Block`) constructor. Also, since `Block` class is abstract the constructors should be `protected` not `public`.

Comment: Agree, updated answer

Comment: i'm sorry I'm not very familiar with C# yet, but what does Point mean or do?  Also can you explain the constructor for line? does that mean it defaults to x=0, y=0?  I'm also new to what base means

Comment: `Point` is the structure that has 2 integer properties: X and Y. I use it to store the figure configuration (shifts from base coordinates. Constructor's `x = 0` means that these parameters are optional, and if caller won't provide provide this parameter it will be defaulted to 0. As to your last question - it looks like you're new to object-oriented programming, you need to learn it. `base` means that we're calling constructor of the base class, see [Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149(v=vs.110).aspx)